# 'this' keyword inside XMLHttpRequest callback refering to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing an issue with the 'this' keyword inside a XMLHttpRequest callback in my React app. The goal here is to update the component state with the response from my XML object. However, inside the callback function of the XML object, the 'this' keyword refers to the object itself instead of the component. I can't seem to get away with this.

How do I reference my component in order to update it's state in this scenario?

```
componentDidMount() {

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;

        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
                //in the line below I cannot access my component due to 'this' keyword refering to xhr.
                this.setState({ teams: JSON.parse(this.responseText).api.teams }); 
                console.log(this.state);
            }
        });

        xhr.open("GET", "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/teams/league/3097");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "xxxxxx");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
        xhr.send(null);
    }
```

**OBS: I have to use XMLHttpRequest to perform this ajax request.**

Comment: () => {} instead of function () {} or function(){}.bind(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {});
```

To

```
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {})
```

So that the callback function doesn't create a new context

Comment: Thank you, TJ. Is there a specific name for this kind of syntax? I remembering using it before, didn't know it kept JS from creating another context.

Comment: It is called an arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions